# ボタンによる画面遷移についてお伺いしたいです。

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 1

    var timer = NSTimer()


    var isAnimating = true

    @IBOutlet weak var alienImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func updateImage(sender: AnyObject) {

        if isAnimating == true {

            timer.invalidate()

            isAnimating = false

        } else {

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("doAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            isAnimating = true

        }


    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: Selector("doAnimation"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    func doAnimation() {

        if counter == 5 {

            counter = 1
        } else {

            counter++

        }

        alienImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).png")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

現在このようなコードで、画像を５つ使ったアニメーションを作成しております。

しかし、ボタンを押しても画像の変化が全く起こりません。
何が原因になっているのでしょうか。

Comment: 回答ではないので、コメント欄に書きますが、いまのままですと、開始画像が、frame1.pngじゃなくて、frame2.pngになりますね。

Comment: 確かにそうです！

ありがとうございます！
それが原因かもしれません！
確認してみます。

Comment: と思い、変更してみたのですが、動きませんでした。
ちょっと模索してみます。

Comment: 前言撤回します。というのは、`alienImage`の初期イメージを、frame1.pngにしておくと、アニメーションをframe2.pngから始める方が、自然だとわかったからです。

Answer (score 1):

御呈示のコードをまったく手を加えず、ただコピー＆ペースとしただけですが、シミュレータで動かしてみると、きっちり起動時からアニメーションしました。ボタンによるポーズと再開も問題ありませんでした。
なので、アニメーションしないというのは、プログラムコード以外、例えばStoryboard上の編集や、Storyboardとコードの接続（Connection）の問題ではないかと、推理できます。そちらをご検証ください。

もうひとつ、調べていただきたいことがあります。
`UIImageView`のプロパティ`image`は、Optional型です。つまりnilを代入してもエラーになりません。イメージの変更に失敗してもエラーを起こさないので、「なにも起こらない」という結果になります。

```
alienImage.image = UIImage(named: "frame\(counter).png")
let result = (alienImage.image != nil) ? "Success" : "Failure"
print(result)
```

このように出力して、イメージを変更できているのか、ご確認ください。

Comment: >>Harawoさん

ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
一度そちらを確認してみます。
本当に何度も失礼しました。

Comment: >>Harawoさん

解決しました！
ありがとうございます！
今後ともしょうもない質問をしてしまうかもしれませんが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: @Kazuho 横から失礼します。解決されたとのことですので、「何が原因だったか」「どのように修正した」といったコメントを残していただけると、後から見る人にも参考になると思います。また、回答のおかげで解決した際には一番参考になった回答をベストアンサーとしてチェックマークを入れることで、この質問が解決済みという印になりますので合わせてご確認ください。